Lower Bound on the Minimum Eigenvalue of a Hollow Symmetric Matrix with Entries in $[0,1]$
Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a hollow symmetric real $n \times n$ matrix, where each entry $A_{i,j} \in [0,1]$ and $A_{i,i} = 0$ for all $i$. I would like to establish a lower bound for the minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_{\min}(\mathbf{A})$ of this matrix. Specifically, I believe that:
$$
\lambda_{\min}(\mathbf{A}) \geq -\frac{n}{2}.
$$
I've verified this bound empirically by running numerical optimization, but I have not been able to provide a rigorous proof. I attempted to use Gershgorin’s Circle Theorem, but the bound it provides is too loose. Other approaches I’ve tried have also failed to yield a satisfactory result.
Could anyone provide insight or a potential proof for this bound?

if $n$ is even, then $-n/2$ is exactly the least eigenvalue of a complete bipartite graph

The proof for $n$ even is in here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585900953
for $n$ odd it seems that the least eigenvalue possible is $-\sqrt{n(n+2)}/2$

@Exodd Thank you!
